# sort array by value that is calculated from the array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, floating-point

I have the lat and lng from a user from the database in an array
and I have my lat and lng

Now I want to calculate the distance and sort the users from my database with that

```
$mylat = $_SESSION['lat'];
$mylng = $_SESSION['lng'];

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($users as $row){
    $dist = 0.0;
    $x1 = $mylng;
    $x2 = $row['lng'];
    $y1 = $mylat;
    $y2 = $row['lat'];

    $dist = acos(sin($x1=deg2rad($x1))*sin($x2=deg2rad($x2))+cos($x1)*cos($x2)*cos(deg2rad($y2) - deg2rad($y1)))*(6378.137);
    $distn = FLOOR ( ROUND($dist,1) * 2 ) / 2 ;
}

sort($distn);

foreach ($users as $row) { 

$dist = 0.0;
    $x1 = $mylng;
    $x2 = $row['lng'];
    $y1 = $mylat;
    $y2 = $row['lat'];

    $dist = acos(sin($x1=deg2rad($x1))*sin($x2=deg2rad($x2))+cos($x1)*cos($x2)*cos(deg2rad($y2) - deg2rad($y1)))*(6378.137);
    $distn = FLOOR ( ROUND($dist,1) * 2 ) / 2 ;

echo $row['username'];
echo $distn;

}
```

So in the first foreach I calculate the distance of each user to me.
Than I want to sort the users after the distance to me and display them
with there name and there distance to me.

```
user1 0.5km distance
user2 1km distance
```

But I wont work.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `sort($distn)` , $dstn does not look like an array

Comment: Sadasivan Pillai , $distn is a value that is calculated for each value in an array with values from an array. array: user1 =>lat=>lng, user2=>lat=>lang, etc...      I want To calculate the distance betwen an user and me and sort it like that

Answer (score 2):

Create a distance function:

```
function getDistance ($lat, $lon)
{
    global $mylng, $mylat;
    $x1 = deg2rad($mylng);
    $x2 = deg2rad($lon);
    $y1 = deg2rad($mylat);
    $y2 = deg2rad($lat);

    $dist = acos(sin($x1)*sin($x2)+cos($x1)*cos($x2)*cos($y2 - $y1))*(6378.137);
    return $dist;
}
```

Create a comparison function:

```
function compareDistance ($user1, $user2)
{
    return getDistance ($user1['lat'], $user1['lng']) - getDistance ($user2['lat'], $user2['lng']);
}
```

Then you can pass your array through `uasort`:

```
uasort ($users, 'compareDistance');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php for more information.

**EDIT:**

Your program could be rewritten:

```
function getDistance ($lat, $lon)
{
    global $mylng, $mylat;

    $x1 = deg2rad($mylng);
    $x2 = deg2rad($lon);
    $y1 = deg2rad($mylat);
    $y2 = deg2rad($lat);

    $dist = acos(sin($x1)*sin($x2)+cos($x1)*cos($x2)*cos($y2 - $y1))*(6378.137);
    return $dist;
}

function compareDistance ($user1, $user2)
{
    return getDistance ($user1['lat'], $user1['lng']) - getDistance ($user2['lat'], $user2['lng']);
}

$mylat = $_SESSION['lat'];
$mylng = $_SESSION['lng'];

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();

uasort ($users, 'compareDistance');

foreach ($users as $row) { 
    $dist = getDistance ($row['lat'], $row['lng']);
    $distn = floor(round($dist,1) * 2) / 2 ;

    echo $row['username']. ": " . $distn . "km distance";
}
```

Comment: I have more than two users. I want to calculate the distance for each user that is created and sort them so that the nearest user is shown first. So the lat and lng are from an array from my database. Do I have to put the function inside the first foreach loop?

Comment: There are two functions, which do you mean?